# New business website (.co.uk) not appearing in google search - up against an established .com website with the same name

Tags: seo, google-search-console, domains, google-search, search-results

A client has started a business in the UK that shares its name with a bigger established business based in Mexico. They operate in completely different market sectors. The name is a single word and made-up so it is pretty unique (not in a dictionary).

The client registered the .co.uk domain - the Mexican business has the .com domain.

We launched a website on the .co.uk domain 8 weeks ago. It's a one-page Wordpress site that is built with a popular theme. We've registered it on Google search console and it confirms the main page is indexed. We've optimised it as we would any other small business site (meta-data, alt tags, page titles etc.). We have also got several back links in place.

To date, the site simply does not register in the key search which is the name of the business (the one it shares with the Mexican business). No sign of it in all the eight pages of search results presented.

There are other references to the UK company in the search results (press articles etc.) but most of the results are for the Mexican company.

If you append something onto the business name in the search - like its location or the products it sells - it comes up on page 1. It also comes up if you put the full domain in (i.e. the business name with .co.uk)

The Search Console says we are getting impressions for the single word search we are seeking but no-one can see this in real world searches.

My questions are:

Is it possible the Mexican company trademarked the company name - and hence Google is blocking the .co.uk domain? (I have researched this online and can't find any trademark directory or explanation of how Google respects trademarks)

Is there any other way we could "tell" Google this is a different business and should be shown in search results?

Any advice would be welcome on this. As you can imagine, the client is very anxious.

Comment: Three questions... 1) Have you searched for the total indexed pages, via the query site:example.co.uk? If the query returns search results, it's not an indexing issue. 2) Have you tried to search for the company name keyword from a spoofed location, somewhere in the UK? Might be Google is localizing the results. 3) Are you using hreflang metadata, and is that somehow constricting the site, you may need more entries or a "default" option in there.